# Plotting by grouped data using Matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm using Matplotlib and Pandas to plot x by y, grouped by z. So I have the following:

```
x = df['ColumnA']
y = df['ColumnB']
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
for key, grp in df.groupby(['ColumnC']):
    plt.plot(grp['ColumnA'], grp['ColumnB'].rolling(window=30).mean(), label=key)
```

I also want to highlight 2 specific values from the total amount of values that will be plotted:

```
ax.legend(('Value1', 'Value2'))
plt.show()
```

This works fine. I just have the 2 values in my legend, but all values are actually plotted. What I actually want, is to be able to specify the colors for the 2 Values above. i.e. red and blue and have all the other values from Column C show on the plot as one color. The objective is to highlight how Value 1 & 2 are performing compared to everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change the colours of the lines of interest.

```py
lines_to_highlight = {
    'Value1': 'red',
    'Value2': 'blue'
}
DEFAULT_COLOR = 'gray'

legend_entries = []  # Lines to show in legend

for line in ax.lines:
    if line.get_label() in lines_to_highlight:
        line.set_color(lines_to_highlight[line.get_label()])

        legend_entries.append(line)
    else:
        line.set_color(DEFAULT_COLOR)
```

Second, create your legend.

```py
ax.legend(
    legend_entries, 
    [entry.get_label() for entry in legend_entries]
)
```

Notes:

- `ax.legend(('Value1', 'Value2'))` doesn't do what you expect. It simply resets the labels for the first two lines you plotted. It doesn't restrict the legend to lines you created with those labels. (The [matplotlib docs](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.legend.html) themselves say that this mistake is easy to make.)
- You must call `ax.legend(...)` *after* setting the line colours. Otherwise, the colours in the legend might not match the ones in the plot.

---

## Example

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot([1, 1, 1], label='one')
ax.plot([2, 2, 2], label='two')
ax.plot([3, 3, 3], label='three')

lines_to_highlight = {
    'one': 'red',
    'three': 'blue'
}
DEFAULT_COLOR = 'gray'

legend_entries = []  # Lines to show in legend

for line in ax.lines:
    if line.get_label() in lines_to_highlight:
        line.set_color(lines_to_highlight[line.get_label()])

        legend_entries.append(line)
    else:
        line.set_color(DEFAULT_COLOR)

ax.legend(
    legend_entries, [entry.get_label() for entry in legend_entries]
)
plt.show()
```

[image: Minimal example]

Comment: It's close, but not quite there. Now the 2 values in the legend are set to red and blue. But everything in the actually plot is gray. I just want the 2 lines that correspond to the values in my legend to be colored.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mark! I made an example and learned that the behaviour of `ax.legend(('Value1', 'Value2'))` isn't what either of us expected and the wrong lines were being labeled. Might want to adjust that in your code.

Not sure that's why your whole plot is gray, though. Maybe try `ax.plot(..., zorder=2)` for lines you want to highlight and `zorder=1` for lines you don't care about?